# How to find the prime factors of a number in Python?

Tags: python

I just started to open for myself programming in python. I know how to find factors for example of 30. I will get [1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30].
But I need this output 30 = 2 * 3 * 5. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please be sure to have a look at existing questions and answers before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to find all prime, unique factors, I'd use the following function:

```
def factor(numberToFactor, arr=list()):
    i = 2
    maximum = numberToFactor / 2 + 1
    while i < maximum:
        if numberToFactor % i == 0:
            return factor(numberToFactor/i,arr + [i])
        i += 1
    return list(set(arr + [numberToFactor]))

print(factor(59511555)) # [3, 5, 1747, 757]
```